# XamarinStudio fails to run failed tests

Tags: mono, xamarin, nunit

I have a bunch of tests over a stubbed out class (throwing NotImplementedException on all methods) which fail to run with a RemotingException like so

[image: Xamarin test runner crash]

Running nunit-console against the DLL with the tests yield the expected results (I've replaced the script to point to a 2.6.3 version of nunit to no avail) with all tests failing.

Once i implement the methods and stop throwing NIE's the test runner runs the tests as usual.

Any ideas on how i could resolve this slight annoyance?

Comment: what version of XamarinStudio are you using?

Comment: 5.1 build 479. Latest one on the Stable channel.

Comment: try the unstable channel, and if you still encounter this problem, then report it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Was on the alpha channel (For great K runtime awesomeness) and downgraded to check. No effect. I'll prepare a test case and report a bug